# costmap_2d doesn't detect Point cloud topic as subscriber

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

I'm trying to use standalone costmap_2d node to check if it works properly.
I've a PointCloud topic beeing well published, and a launch file with the corresponding lines shown below (I show only the lines corresponding to the costmap_2d node and it's visualitzation).

_________________________________ launch file lines _________________________

```
<!-- Run the costmap node -->
<node name="costmap_node" pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_node" >
  <rosparam file="$(find costmap_2d)/launch/example_params.yaml" command="load" ns="costmap" />
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
</node>

<!-- Publishes the voxel grid to rviz for display -->
<node pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_markers" name="voxel_visualizer">
    <remap from="voxel_grid" to="/costmap_node/costmap/voxel_grid"/>
</node>
```

---

As you see, I've the parameters at the file: example_params.yaml, wich contain the lines:

________________________________example_params.yaml _____________________________

```
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 1.0

publish_voxel_map: true

static_map: false

rolling_window: true
width: 6.0
height: 6.0
resolution: 0.025

map_type: voxel
origin_z: 0.0
z_resolution: 0.2
z_voxels: 10
unknown_threshold: 10
mark_threshold: 0

transform_tolerance: 0.3
obstacle_range: 2.5
max_obstacle_height: 2.0
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.325, -0.325], [-0.325, 0.325], [0.325, 0.325], [0.46, 0.0], [0.325, -0.325]]

footprint_padding: 0.01
inflation_radius: 0.55
cost_scaling_factor: 10.0
lethal_cost_threshold: 100
observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor 
point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: /tf_pmd_camcube, data_type: PointCloud, topic: /output_obstacle, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

The point cloud topic has been published correctly with this parameters shown, but the problem is that the costmap_2d doesn't subscrib to this topic. If I check it using rxgraph, the point cloud doesn't appear at the costmap subscribers. only appear /tf and /clock.

Could anyone help me to find what I'm mistaken?

Thanks in advance,

Àngel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27839/costmap_2d-doesn%27t-detect-point-cloud-topic-as-subscriber/) by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2012-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-02-17**:
Can you post a screenshot of `rxgraph` around costmap?

**Comment by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on 2012-02-18**:
Hi, you could see the rxgraph here : http://postimage.org/image/tpq3idwxr/ the topic that I want to subscribe the costmap_node is the publisher of /normal_estimation node: /output_obstacle, thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I founded a way to do that, so I will close it as answered.

Thank to everyone.

Àngel.

---

Originally posted by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) with karma: 74 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AliAs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20060/alias/) on 2014-08-26**:
It was more appreciated if you put your solution here...